# Faster alternative to NSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an equation, which I am trying to solve using `NSolve` in *Mathematica*. Here is how I do it:

```
T == (0.000242895 E^(-(2.09472*10^11/(5.70068*10^8 + 
            7.76206*10^12 T))))/(1 + 
    0.969073 E^(-(4.18945*10^11/(5.70068*10^8 + 7.76206*10^12 T))) - 
    1.96883 Cos[8.77331*10^6/(2.28027*10^9 + 7.76206*10^12 T)])

NSolve[T == (0.000242895 E^(-(2.09472*10^11/(5.70068*10^8 + 
             7.76206*10^12 T))))/(1 + 
     0.969073 E^(-(4.18945*10^11/(5.70068*10^8 + 7.76206*10^12 T))) - 
     1.96883 Cos[8.77331*10^6/(2.28027*10^9 + 7.76206*10^12 T)])
 , {T}, Reals]
```

The problem is that it takes a long time (~1min) to find a solution. Is there a faster way to obtain a solution other than using `NSolve`?

Comment: Perhaps by restricting the interval for NSolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator of your expression goes through zero at approximately T=215. The other solution is T=0. If you want the non-zero solution simply use

```
FindRoot[denom,{T,T0}]
```

where T0 is most any positive number. This takes about a millisecond.

Comment: This implicitly assumes that there are only 2 solutions: A zero and a non-zero solution. It may happen that there are 3, so I think I need to use NSolve

Comment: The limits of your function for large positive or negative T are both unity. There is a singularity at about 215. The root at zero may be multiple, but numerical inaccuracies prevent its resolution. Does NSolve give you 3 roots? Where?